# ACL permissions still broken after 4.6.8 upgrade

Tags: acl, 4.6.6

I was running 4.6.6 and noticed I was unable to access some of the settings for an event. I then noticed I didn't have permission to get to other areas of CiviCRM, this in spite of having full admin access.

I saw the bulletin regarding 4.6.6 breaking ACL permissions, so I just upgraded to 4.6.8, but the permissions are still broken - I can't get into any of the administrative functions of CiviCRM at all, and I'm kind of freaking out. As usual, this couldn't have happened at a worse possible time - we have our National Convention in less than 30 days and I desperately need to make changes to my event settings and price sets.

We're running Drupal 7.3.8 and Civi 4.6.8. We have 50 states set up with content access control controlled by smart groups based on state. Any help anyone can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I was wondering if you figured out your problem, and if so, whether you could post an answer - or comment on an answer that worked for you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ACL bugs fixed in the most recent point releases wouldn't affect a full administrator.  I believe it's unrelated to your current problem.

Your symptoms sound like you're logging in over HTTP, but with HTTPS forced to on.  Try logging in over HTTPS and see if your problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

if you think you've come across a bug then check the issue tracker here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/issues/?jql=text%20~%20acl%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC

If it's not already in there then feel free to report the issue, with steps on how to recreate the problem. Ie: Exactly what ACLs are you using, how are your users/permissions set up, how someone can you recreate the issues in a fresh installation of CiviCRM.

But if you think you've identified a security issue then you can follow the guidance here: https://civicrm.org/security